# select from a list based on digits

Tags: list-manipulation

I wish to know how do I count the number of occurrences of numbers that end in digits d. e.g. Say I create a list of Divisors of 12! I now want to count those divisors that end in 12. Like 12 & 112 would qualify but 120 would not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases you can use [`Mod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mod.html):

```
d = Divisors[12!];
last2 = Mod[d, 10^2];

Count[last2, 12]
Pick[d, last2, 12]
```

> ```
> 11
>
> {12, 112, 512, 1512, 2112, 6912, 19712, 28512, 64512, 266112, 870912}
> ```

If the sequence you are looking for starts with zero, e.g. you are searching for `01` and you want `1001` to match but `1` not to match, you could use:

```
Cases[Range[1500], x_ /; MatchQ[IntegerDigits @ x, {___, 0, 1}]]
```

> ```
> {101, 201, 301, 401, 501, 601, 701, 801, 901, 1001, 1101, 1201, 1301, 1401}
> ```

This code is not vectorized so it is unlikely to be very fast but it does conserve memory; if speed is important let me know.

Comment: Nice math!. I did not think/know that mod 12 would pick all values that end up with 12 and nothing else. But I guess since these values are divisors, then it should follow.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, but that's not actually what I wrote. :^)  I'm just using mod 100 to pull the last two digits, then using standard pattern matching to check the result.

Comment: You are right, I saw Mod there with 12 next to it. Need new glasses. Either way, smart method

Answer (score 2):

one way (if you do not want the list itself, just the count *)

```
lst = IntegerDigits[Divisors[12!]];
k = 0;
If[ Length[#] > 1 && FromDigits[Take[#, -2]] == 12, k++] & /@ lst;
k
(* 11 *)
```

And if you want the list also:

```
lst = IntegerDigits[Divisors[12!]];
lst2 = Cases[lst, x_ /; Length[x] > 1 && FromDigits[Take[x, -2]] == 12];
Length[lst2]
(* 11 *)
```

Or using `Select`

```
lst = IntegerDigits[Divisors[12!]];
Length@Select[lst, (Length[#] > 1 && FromDigits[Take[#, -2]] == 12) &];
(* 11 *)
```

Comment: Also `Count[lst, x_ /; Last@IntegerDigits[x] == 2]` as a modification of the second method to just count.

Comment: @acl - very nice ! didn't know that one can plug a condition into "Count".

Comment: note he wanted to match the last two digits.

Comment: @george2079 opps, ok, easy to fix, thanks. will do that now.

Comment: @eldo patterns can include conditions wherever they're allowed